# Как во vuejs передать данные из файла формата *.json?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, frontend

нашел следующее:
Метод JSON.parse

Вызов JSON.parse(str) превратит строку с данными в формате JSON в JavaScript-объект/массив/значение.

Например:

```
var numbers = "[0, 1, 2, 3]";

numbers = JSON.parse(numbers);

alert( numbers[1] ); // 1
```

Или так:

```
var user = '{ "name": "Вася", "age": 35, "isAdmin": false, "friends": [0,1,2,3] }';

user = JSON.parse(user);

alert( user.friends[1] ); // 1
```

Данные могут быть сколь угодно сложными, объекты и массивы могут включать в себя другие объекты и массивы. Главное, чтобы они соответствовали формату.

сгенерировал свой json попробовал по аналогии с примером ничего не вышло(страница перестала отрисовываться). 
В частности вот кусок кода после добавления которого страница "ломается":

Мне не совсем ясно как данный метод поймет где лежит файл json.
Если это важно то для сборки используется webpack. 
В этом деле я новичок, поэтому буду рад любой помощи. 
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import myJsonFile from 'file.json'
```

и для myJsonFile  не нужно делать JSON.parse

Comment: Спасибо большое.